# Best practice for partial git branches merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-workflow

Our client changed is mind about some big new features (lets call it FA) for one of our project and now he wants a subset of this feature but integrated in a different way (lets call it FB)  and then later put all the initial requested features but merged with the changes done in FB and overlapping changes will be taken from FB.

I have this git situation:

- master branch with the stable release that is now on production
- FA branch

Now I created a new branch FB from master.

I need to integrate some changes from FA, then do some work and later merge completely FA in FB and at the end put all to master branch

What is the best way to do this without becoming mad and preserving when possible commit history from FA and FB

Answer (score 0):

You could `cherry-pick` some of the commits from your **FA** branch into your **FB**. Using `cherry-pick` you can select which commits you want to take out from **FA** and integrate them into your **FB**.

Say you are on your **FB** branch and you want to integrate some commits from **FA**.

First, you would get a list of all of the commits on your **FA** branch

```
git log --oneline
```

Now, when you got all of the commits - SHAs and commit messages at your display

```
git checkout FB

git cherry-pick SHA
```

You can also pass `--edit` tag to the above instruction. It will allow you to edit the commit messages.

Another useful thing to note, you can `cherry-pick` into a *staging area* using `--no-commit` option. This will put cherry-picked commit into a staging area. At this point you can amend the *staging area* and commit either partially or in full.

If you want to keep a track where you cherry picked from. You can add `-x` option. This will add source SHA to commit message. Also if you want to track who cherry picked what, use `--signeoff` option. It will add users username in the commit message.

Hope it helps.

**Reference**

[cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Comment: it is not so simple... i need to pick not all the changes from commits